# Shared or private resources on azure portal

Tags: azure

My company has a Microsoft account (office365, mails, ...)

I plan to work with azure virtual machines.

There is something strange: all my virtual machines and all my azure resources (websites, ...) are private. My collegues cannot manage them. They can connect with ssh but they don’t see entry in there azure portal account.

Is there a way to share all the azure resources in the whole company, for all users ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign role to see  azure resources. In azure we have a bunch of predefined roles for example - reader. If you assign reader role at the subscription level, so the member can read all resources located in that subscription, but can not make any changes. Here can you read more about [roles based access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)

Why users can connect to vm, but can't see in the portal? My bet is that VM ports are not blocked and all internet can connect to those VM's.

Comment: Thanks but where can we assign this roles ?

Comment: Once you open resource group, you will see "Access control (IAM)" link. From there you can control access to the RG